# Compass background-image(linear-gradient) not working on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css, sass, gradient, compass-sass

This gradient done using SASS and Compass does not work in any version of Internet Explorer:

```
@include background-image(linear-gradient(left, rgba(241,236,236,0.95), rgba(241,236,236,0.9), rgba(241,236,236,0.85), rgba(241,236,236,0.8), rgba(241,236,236,0.75), rgba(241,236,236,0.4)));
```

It translates to this CSS:

```
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 50%, 100% 50%, color-stop(0%, rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.95)), color-stop(20%, rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.9)), color-stop(40%, rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.85)), color-stop(60%, rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.8)), color-stop(80%, rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.75)), color-stop(100%, rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.4)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.95), rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.9), rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.85), rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.8), rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.75), rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.4));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.95), rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.9), rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.85), rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.8), rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.75), rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.4));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.95), rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.9), rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.85), rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.8), rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.75), rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.4));
  background-image: linear-gradient(left, rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.95), rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.9), rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.85), rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.8), rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.75), rgba(241, 236, 236, 0.4));
```

So what do you do to solve this with IE?

I'm testting it with internet explorer 11. I need it to work from IE9+

As helped below I found for now the answer to cover IE10+, this helped me:

```
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(241,236,236,0.95), rgba(241,236,236,0.9), rgba(241,236,236,0.85), rgba(241,236,236,0.8), rgba(241,236,236,0.75), rgba(241,236,236,0.4)); /* IE10+ */
```

After I tried the following for IE9 but did not work:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f1ecec', endColorstr='#fffafa',GradientType=1 );
```

What can I use to cover annoying IE9?

Comment: Please specify the IE version(s) you're testing with, and also the versions you need it to work in. CSS gradients need different syntax in older IE versions.

Comment: @Spudley I added the version I use on the question. I need it to work from IE9+

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a filter for IE6-9 that looks like:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(...)
```

and for IE10+

```
-ms-linear-gradient
```

I believe IE6-9 may only support 2 color stops. The best thing i can give you too help is this:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Amazing tool for this stuff :)

If you "import" your css into the tool you get:

```
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(241,236,236,0.95) 0%, rgba(241,236,236,0.75) 80%, rgba(241,236,236,0.4) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(241,236,236,0.95)), color-stop(80%,rgba(241,236,236,0.75)), color-stop(100%,rgba(241,236,236,0.4))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(241,236,236,0.95) 0%,rgba(241,236,236,0.75) 80%,rgba(241,236,236,0.4) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(241,236,236,0.95) 0%,rgba(241,236,236,0.75) 80%,rgba(241,236,236,0.4) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(241,236,236,0.95) 0%,rgba(241,236,236,0.75) 80%,rgba(241,236,236,0.4) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(241,236,236,0.95) 0%,rgba(241,236,236,0.75) 80%,rgba(241,236,236,0.4) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f2f1ecec', endColorstr='#66f1ecec',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

Support for full multi-stop gradients with IE9 (using SVG).
Add a "gradient" class to all your elements that have a gradient, and add the following override to your HTML to complete the IE9 support:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

... or even the SCSS version

```
// needs latest Compass, add '@import "compass"' to your scss
@include filter-gradient(#f2f1ecec, #66f1ecec, vertical); // IE6-8
// IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none'
$experimental-support-for-svg: true;
@include background-image(linear-gradient(top,  rgba(241,236,236,0.95) 0%,rgba(241,236,236,0.75) 80%,rgba(241,236,236,0.4) 100%));
```

Heres a link to your imported css which should help you: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#f1ecec+0,f1ecec+100&0.95+0,0.75+80,0.4+100;Custom

Comment: IE10+ does not require `-ms-`. No stable version of IE uses `-ms-` for gradients. Every source that says otherwise is wrong.

Comment: True, no stable version does, its the `consumer preview` version that does supposedly. But won't hurt adding it in, if your going to support all the other browser prefixes, you may as well add another one :P

Comment: Sure if you want to add unnecessary bloat to your stylesheet, by all means, but please don't recommend it to others. It's that sort of attitude that makes prefixes so brittle.

Comment: You call is unnecessary bloat, i call it covering all bases. Sure its a small percentage of market share that uses the browser, but if you're going to go to the length of supporting everything else, i see no issue with it. I would rather provide the information and let him make the decision, than presume i know what's best for him.

Comment: @Lee I tried your solution and when I added the ms prefix. it worked for IE10+. But afterwards I tried filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(...) but it does not work in IE9 which I need to cover! So IE10+ good, IE9 not good

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero if you tick the `IE9 Support` checkbox under the code on the colorzilla link, it will give you an additional bit of code and explanation. Essentially you have to cancel the filter you add for IE6-8 support and use an SVG by looks of it. See my edit

Comment: @Lee I checked this out, but I really do not understand what you need to do... It seems you need to cancel the filter for IE6-8 and insert filter none. But that does not make any sense!!! Then the linear-gradient should work... I will check what that SVG is...

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero I've posted a link with your CSS imported, just follow it closely. Basically IE6-8 uses that funky filter, IE10+ should work with the normal linear-gradient, except some of the first versions of IE10 that require the `-ms` prefixed version as you found out. IE9 is the wildcard, you must cancel the filter out for IE9 only, and use a special SVG image background

Comment: You should use feature detection like Modernizr instead of conditional tags and extra classes to target browsers that need a filter fallback.

Comment: @DuncanWalker: I use modernizr a lot myself, and it does come in handy. But your statement that you "should use" modernizr is primarily opinion based, and if you get into the meat of things, could say that CSS dependant on JS goes against the "separation of concerns". Essentially Modernizr is one approach with a list if Pro's and Con's, just as conditional CSS or server side browser sniffing has a list of Pro's and Con's. Its up to each developer to learn about each one and decide what they feel is best approach, but that's not what SO is here for...

Answer (score 2):

This dont work in IE11

```
background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ff0000,#ffff00);
```

This work and show like then webkit version

```
background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #ff0000,#ffff00);
```

The webkit also support the ...deg mode, but dont work as the explorer does, this is the equivalent in webkit.

```
-webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, #ff0000,#ffff00);
```

Note: Chrome understand the no webkit version as explorer does.